# MongoDB slows down every 2 hours and 10 minutes accurately

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the past 3 months, my MongoDB server getting very slow every 2 hours and 10 minutes, very accurate.

**My Server configuration:**

- 3 replica set, and for the purpose of data backup, 1 of them has 3600 seconds delay.
- No slave servers to the 3 masters in the replica set.
- Use mongoose + node.js to provide rest api.
- About 9 reads and 1.5 writes per second in average in the 24 hours statistics data.

**What I did** after searching stackoverflow and google:

- Restart the server CANNOT change the slow interval 2 hours and 10 minutes
- Create index to all the fields I query, no impact
- Delete data file in one server and use another one to recovery, then delete anohter and recovery back, no impact
- Shift primary server, no impact
- Run 'currentOps' when the database is slow, I can see a lot of query hung there, too many logs to paste here, but didn't see some abnormal query.
- In mongo console, check "serverStatus" when the database is slow, the command waiting until the database is recovered.
- No memory usage increase from "top" command when database is slow.
- rest api which does not access database works well.

I guess there might be something locking, the most potential cause is that it may be building index. There are **something special** in my database:

- I have about 14000 collections in one database, and is increasing. There may be 1 to 3000 records in one collections.
- Both the number of collections and the number records are increasing dynamically.
- Index fields will be specified when creating new collection.

I have been obsessed by this issue for 3 months. Any comments/suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Here are **some logs** from my log file:

> Fri Jul  5 **15:20:11**.040 [conn2765] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 0, after backgroundFlushing: 0, after connections: 0, after cursors: 0, after dur: 0, after extra_info: 0, after globalLock: 0, after indexCounters: 0, after locks: 0, after network: 0, after opcounters: 0, after opcountersRepl: 0, after recordStats: 222694, after repl: 222694, at end: 222694 }
>
> Fri Jul  5 **17:30:09**.367 [conn4711] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 0, after backgroundFlushing: 0, after connections: 0, after cursors: 0, after dur: 0, after extra_info: 0, after globalLock: 0, after indexCounters: 0, after locks: 0, after network: 0, after opcounters: 0, after opcountersRepl: 0, after recordStats: 199498, after repl: 199498, at end: 199528 }
>
> Fri Jul  5 **19:40:12**.697 [conn6488] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 0, after backgroundFlushing: 0, after connections: 0, after cursors: 0, after dur: 0, after extra_info: 0, after globalLock: 0, after indexCounters: 0, after locks: 0, after network: 0, after opcounters: 0, after opcountersRepl: 0, after recordStats: 204061, after repl: 204061, at end: 204081 }

Here are the screen shot of my pingdom report, the server down 4 minutes every 2 hours and 7 minutes. In the beginning, the server down 2 minutes every 2 hours and 6 minutes.
[image: report from pingdom]

[EDIT 1] More monitor result from host provider:
[CPU http://i.minus.com/iZBNyMPzLSLRr.png](http://i.minus.com/iZBNyMPzLSLRr.png)
[DiskIO http://i.minus.com/ivgrHr0Ghoz92.png](http://i.minus.com/ivgrHr0Ghoz92.png)
[Connections http://i.minus.com/itbfYq0SSMlNs.png](http://i.minus.com/itbfYq0SSMlNs.png)
The periodically increased connections is because connections are waiting, and the count for current connection will accumulate until database is unblocked. **This is not because of huge traffic.**

Comment: What hosting services you are using to host your application and database replicas?

Comment: linode.com, 1G RAM/8 Cores/24GB Disk plan

Comment: "No slave servers to the 3 masters in the replica set. " makes no sense, as there is no such thing as multi-master in MongoDB

Comment: linode has some basic graphs around "what the server is doing", what do those graphs tell you?

Comment: There is no abnormal wave in the graph, CPU is maintain around 6%, no visible changes in network traffic.

Comment: @Derick I may described not accurately here. I mean, I didn't set slave server for server in the replica set. There is only 3 machines in the replica set. node.js will read from the primary server. When primary is down, a secondary will be voted to be the new primary.

Comment: What is the disk doing (iostat) when the server is marked down?

Comment: @RobMoore, thanks a lot for your question. I've added 3 more images for CPU/IO/Connections. The IO increase when db is blocking, I think it should be caused by the concurrent connections which is waiting or something blocking database.

Comment: Have you changed the flush/sync interval (syncdelay is the option if I remember)? Are you using journaling? I think there is something causing the server to flush the pages to disk, that is causing MongoDB to 'hang' waiting for the I/O to finish and connections to backup.

Comment: @RobMoore I use 64bit machine and it enables journal automatically. For syncdelay and journalCommitInterval, I just use default values. which should be: syncdelay=60seconds, and journalCommitInterval=100ms. Thanks a lot for your comment. I'm now adding more monitors to disk/io/network/cpu/memory.

Comment: Your point on dynamically creating collections and indexes can cause an issue. Indexes will block all other ops on database unless you specify to do a background index build (caveat: you can only have one background build on the primary at a time, and is relatively expensive op). If you're periodically dynamically creating large collections and then building an index of that data after the fact, that could cause the pile up. Have you ran the profiler to catch any long running ops?

Comment: @DylanTong Yes, thanks a lot for the reminder. I noticed this from document, but when I create a collection, the collection is empty. Actually the collection will be created randomly. In work hour, every 5 minutes, and in midnight, every 15 minutes. But the lock happens every 2 hours and 7 minutes, very actually, never changed.

Comment: @MasonZhang It would be interesting to see what mongostat (or MMS http://www.10gen.com/products/mongodb-management-service) reports during that time. The periodic nature of the issue is particularly interesting. MongoDB doesn't normally perform anything periodic during that interval (definitely not that heavy duty). The only possibility of something periodic and heavy duty would be a mass chunk migration (a result of a heavy writes and a bad shard key) in a sharded cluster and the balancer has been scheduled to run every 130minutes. Do you have any cron jobs scheduled on the box?

Comment: @DylanTong I have several months' monitor data on 10gen's MMS, however I'm not able to read anything special from MMS. I think the MMS client on my server will call function "serverStatus" periodically to report status to MMS. I didn't set cron jobs on mongodb. Thanks a lot for the reply and thoughts on my situation. I have migrated my database to DynamoDB, and not it works very well: http://www.masonzhang.com/2013/07/lean7-migrate-from-mongodb-to-dynamodb.html

Comment: Sorry, we couldn't figure it out. Could you share the version of MongoDB you were using? Also, were you running a sharded collection--if so, what were your balancer settings? Thanks

Comment: I thought of another possibility. If the syncdelay setting (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/) was accidentally changed to a large number like 7800 (130min), this could cause a big periodic IO bottleneck. The syncdelay setting specifies the frequency of when dirty pages are flushed to disk asychronously. If the delay is set to 130min, there will probably be alot of dirty pages that need to be flushed to disk causing the big periodic IO bottleneck. Default is 60, but in prod, I see people frequently use a low number like 5 with fast disks.

Comment: Hi @DylanTong, Thanks a lot for the analysis and help on my question. I really appreciate your efforts here. I'm no shifted to DynamoDB to avoid database management by engineer. I really love MongoDB and there are a lot of favorite things. I wrote a blog post to help people select MongoDB over DynamoDB: http://www.masonzhang.com/2013/08/7-reasons-you-should-use-mongodb-over.html

Comment: @MasonZhang I enjoy helping people out in the community. Your blog post was a good read--had some very good points.

Comment: Having a similar behavior on my setup, hosted on rackspace and a ruby client rather than nodeJS. Any ideas what on earth is happening every 2 hours and 10 minutes on a mongo replicaset?

Comment: @JAR.JAR.beans //hand, I'm not alone. I searched google and no one else reporting this issue.

Answer (score 3):

We found a specific 2:10 issue. In our case, it was an execution of dbStats by MMS.
We had to upgrade the cluter and the issue got resolved.

Comment: glad to see that you found the reason, but now I've moved to dynamodb and simpledb, and don't need care about ops any more.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue. I'd start with `mongostat` / `mongotop` and work your way from there. Identify the predominant workload with `mongostat`, and then find out which collection is causing that activity.

For my particular case, I have a cron job that deletes obsoletes records. It turns out that the way the replica set propagates this commands is extremely resource intensive. For example, I would delete 3m records from a collection, that happens on the replica set master. For some reason, this propagation makes all secondaries work intensively in the subsequent propagation.

If you can see things in `db.currentOp`, I would focus on the ones that have long running time and try to pinpoint the root cause by elimination from there.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean a replicaset with 3 nodes instead of "3 replica set".

If you are still experiencing the same issue. Here is my opinion:

1. Since you are running your server in linode.com. Your server is actually a virtual machine and you are sharing resources with others. The periodic slow down may be due to others running having disk load periodically. Since you have looked into so many different possibilities already, this may be an option for you even it takes a bit of effort.
2. This is definitely caused by a job ran by mongodb or your system. Please try to look for any job that runs regularly. For example, try to remove the 3600 seconds delay on one of your secondary. Even that is not 2 hour and 10 minutes, but that may be a trigger of it.

I can't post my suggestions in the comment since it doesn't allow me to. So, I am posting this as an answer.